# add self class to models rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models:

```
Class Model1

end

Class Model2

end

Class Model3

end
```

I have this code:

```
scope :created_between, lambda { |start_time, end_time| where(:created_at => (start_time...end_time)) }

class << self
 ## Class methods for calculating searches
 def created_today
  today = Time.zone.now
  created_between(today.beginning_of_day, today.end_of_day)
 end

 def created_yesterday
  yesterday = Time.zone.now - 1.day
  created_between(yesterday.beginning_of_day, yesterday.end_of_day)
 end

 def created_last_week
  start_time = (Time.zone.now - 1.week).beginning_of_day
  end_time = Time.zone.now
  created_between(start_time, end_time)
 end

 def created_last_month
  start_time = (Time.zone.now - 1.month).beginning_of_day
  end_time = Time.zone.now
  created_between(start_time, end_time)
 end

 def created_last_year
  start_time = (Time.zone.now - 1.year).beginning_of_day
  end_time = Time.zone.now
  created_between(start_time, end_time)
 end
```

end

I need add this code to 3 models but I don't want repeat the code inside each model.

How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I wouldn't use a scope for the first method. you can just do that with another class method that takes two arguments, and then you won't need the lamba.

Comment: Thank you, can you add a example?

Comment: Just do exactly what you did with the other methods, but have the method take two arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
module CommonClassFunctions

 def self.included(base)
   base.send :extend, ClassMethods
 end

 module ClassMethods
   ## Class methods for calculating searches
   def created_today
    today = Time.zone.now
    created_between(today.beginning_of_day, today.end_of_day)
   end

   def created_yesterday
    yesterday = Time.zone.now - 1.day
    created_between(yesterday.beginning_of_day, yesterday.end_of_day)
   end

   def created_last_week
    start_time = (Time.zone.now - 1.week).beginning_of_day
    end_time = Time.zone.now
    created_between(start_time, end_time)
   end

   def created_last_month
    start_time = (Time.zone.now - 1.month).beginning_of_day
    end_time = Time.zone.now
    created_between(start_time, end_time)
   end

   def created_last_year
    start_time = (Time.zone.now - 1.year).beginning_of_day
    end_time = Time.zone.now
    created_between(start_time, end_time)
   end
  end
end

Class Model1
  include CommonClassFunctions
end

Class Model2
  include CommonClassFunctions
end

Class Model3
  include CommonClassFunctions
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much is complete this example.

Comment: Good answer :), Why not a `AS::Concern`? It's simpler and gives slightly more functionality. May I edit the answer to use  `ActiveSupport::Concern`?

Answer (score 3):

You can define a module with this methods, then include it on the 3 models.

Like :

```
module Searcheable
  def created_today
    .
    . 
    .
    .
    .
  end
end
```

Then on the classes:

```
class Model1
  extend Searcheable
end

class Model2
  extend Searcheable
end

class Model3
  extend Searcheable
end
```

Comment: Thank you in what folder of my rails project create file with the module?

Comment: This module could go on lib folder.

Comment: good (probably better) answer - composition is often better than inheritance! Although it still depends on the usecase ...

Comment: You should be using extend instead of include to replicate the `class << self` class method definition in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with inheritance

```
class Model
  class << self
    def created_today
      puts "created today from Model"
    end
  end
end

class Model1 < Model

end

class Model2 < Model

end

class Model3 < Model

end

Model1.created_today
# output: created today from Model
```